# spring validation java pattern multiple mail

Tags: java, regex, spring, validation, email

I have problems with the regex. somehow the online regextester does not work with the pattern.

I would like to allow

```
mymail@whatever.com
```

and

```
mymail1@whatever.com;mymail2@whatever.com;mymail3@whatever.com
```

so one without semicolon and multiple with semicolon between, but not on the end

what I have:

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

public EmailValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}

public boolean valid(final String email) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the pattern in between the anchors as the *single* email matching subpattern, and use it to build the final pattern:

```
private static final String SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN = "[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})";
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^" + SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN + "(?:;" + SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN + ")*$";
```

Your pattern will look like [the one here](https://regex101.com/r/Qzau6M/1).

- `^` - will assert the start of string
- `SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN` - will match 1 email
- `(?:;<SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN>)*` - will match 0 or more sequences of:

  - `;` -  a `;`
  - `<SINGLE_EMAIL_PATTERN>` - a single email
- `$` - will assert the end of string.

Comment: thx, it works fine and looks nice.
tested with:
mymail1@whatever.com:true  mymail1@whatever.com;mymail2@whatever.com;mymail3@whatever.com:true
  mymail1@whatever.com;mymail2@whatever.com;mymail3@whatever.com;:false
mymail1@whatever.com;:false

Answer (score 1):

See if this one works for you:

```
@Test
public void testValidEmail(){
        String regex =
                    "(([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]{2,4}))(((;|,|; | ;| ; | , | ,){1}"
                    +"([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\@([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+\\.([A-Za-z]{2,4}))*)";
        Boolean matches = Pattern.matches(regex, "mymail1@whatever.com;mymail2@whatever.com;mymail3@whatever.com");
        Assert.assertTrue(matches); 
}
```